# issue with JWT tokens with apollo server and express.js

Tags: express, authentication, oauth-2.0, graphql, jwt

i have created a simple authentication system, everything is works well, but i think there is something not normal in the cycle of accessToken and refreshToken, i did like this:
jwt.js:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';


const { sign, verify } = jwt;

const setTokens = ({ uid, username, email, role }) => {

    const user = { user: { uid, username, email, role } };

    const accessToken = sign(user, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_DURATION,
    });
    const refreshToken = sign(user, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_DURATION,
    });
    return { uid, username, email, role, accessToken, refreshToken };
};

const validateAccessToken = (token) => {
    try {
        return verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

    } catch (error) {
        if (error.message !== 'jwt expired') {
            console.error(`Access token error: ${error.message}`);
        }
    }
};

const validateRefreshToken = (token) => {
    try {
        return verify(token, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET);
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.message !== 'jwt expired') {
            console.error(`Refresh token error: ${error.message}`);
        }
    }
};



export { setTokens, validateAccessToken, validateRefreshToken };
```

this context.js:

```
import { setTokens, validateAccessToken, validateRefreshToken } from './jwt.js';

export const context = async({ req, res }) => {
    let accessToken = req.headers['x-access-token'] ? req.headers['x-access-token'].replace(/^null$/, '') : '';
    let refreshToken = req.headers['x-refresh-token'] ? req.headers['x-refresh-token'].replace(/^null$/, '') : '';
    let uid = null;

    if (accessToken) {
        const decodedAccessToken = validateAccessToken(accessToken);
        uid = decodedAccessToken && decodedAccessToken.user && decodedAccessToken.user.uid ?
            decodedAccessToken.user.uid : null;

    }

    if (!uid && refreshToken) {
        const tokenUser = validateRefreshToken(refreshToken);
        if (tokenUser && tokenUser.user) {
            uid = tokenUser.user.uid;
            const { accessToken, refreshToken } = setTokens(tokenUser.user);
            res.set({
                "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "x-access-token,x-refresh-token",
                "x-access-token": accessToken,
                "x-refresh-token": refreshToken
            });


        } else {
            console.info(`Invalid/expired access token presented but refreshToken null or missing!`);
        }
    }

    return { req, res, uid };
};
```

and surly i have add the context.js in the server :

```
app.use(
    '/graphql',
    cors(),
    bodyParser.json(),
    expressMiddleware(server, {
        context: context,
    }),
);
```

i have make the accessToken duration is 1m and refreshToken for 10m.... as i have understood, user must stay logged in forever, since everytime the accessToken expires, server will check the refreshToken, and generate new pair with same duration? but after i tried it, its just expired after 10m (the duration for refreshToken), any one can explain this? and i have something worong?

Comment: Is your client saving the new tokens when it gets them and then presenting them on the next request?